# Dynamically including directive in an AngularJS partial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, partials

I have a list of directives (normally form fields and custom form controls). Now I will get the list of directive names from backend to use to build a form.

It basically creates a dynamic form where I don't know what all form fields are in the form (it depends on the JSON config file I get from the backend).

Sample JSON:

```
field1 : {
     type: 'text',
     directive : 'directive1'
},
field2: {
     type : 'dropdown',
     directive : 'dropdown-directive'
}
```

Can I do something similar in AngularJS, and if possible, how?

Answer (score 1):

Use the $compile service against the scope. This will allow you to compile angular code which can be appended to a container.

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8jjZ/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div custom-elements="myData.elements"></div>
    <p>{{user}}</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mod = angular.module("myApp", []);

mod.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.elements = {
        field1 :{ type: 'text', directive : 'directive1' },
        field2: { type : 'dropdown', directive : 'dropdown-directive' }
    }; 
});

mod.directive("customElements", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            customElements: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var prop,
                elems = scope.customElements,
                currElem,
                compiled;
            for (prop in elems) {
                currElem = elems[prop];
                console.log("Working on " + prop);
                //compile input against parent scope. Assuming directives are attributes, but adapt to your scenario:
                compiled = $compile('<div ' + currElem.directive + '></div>')(scope.$parent);

                //append this to customElements
                element.append(compiled);
            }
        }
    }
});

mod.directive("directive1", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: '<div>Whoa! I am directive 1<br><input type="text" ng-model="user.name"></div>'
    }
});

mod.directive("dropdownDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: '<div>I am another directive<br><select ng-model="user.color"><option value="blue">blue</option><option value="green">Green</option></div>'
    }
});
```

The customElement directive just creates the directive as if it were an attribute on an element. This is a very simple example, but should get you started on what you are looking to do where you can update the logic that builds the elements/directive accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the solution, i was looking something similar to your solution.